# Align image with text block

Tags: html, css

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="center" style="margin: auto;">
 <img src="./Resources/document.png" style="vertical-align: middle;" />
 <p style="display: inline-block">Never lose an email again</p>
 <p style="font-size: 0.8em">Second paragrah the wants to have indentation</p>
</div>
```

The result I want is [image: The exapmple]

Note the image is vertical align with the first text block, and the second text block has the right indentation. And I want to contain the whole elements with container with flexible padding like `width:50%`

Currently my code is

`<div class="center" style="margin: auto;">
    <img src="./Resources/document.png" style="vertical-align: middle;" />
    <p style="display: inline-block">Never lose an email again</p>
</div>`

However the second text block does not indent properly.

Comment: can you please add your code into snippet?.

Comment: do you mean to set padding to the sub text (under title)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use [`FontAwesome`](https://fontawesome.com) icons or something similar rather than using images to achieve your end result.

The updated snippet replicating your attached screenshot -

```css
.small {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.box {
  width: 30%;
  margin-left: 35%;
  margin-right: 35%;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.box:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  color: green;
  font-size: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -33px;
  margin-top: -5px;
}

.magnify:before {
  content: "\f002";
}

.book:before {
  content: "\f02d";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<div class="box magnify">
  <p>Never lose an email again</p>
  <p class="small">Second paragrah the wants to have indentation Second paragrah the wants to have indentation Second paragrah the wants to have indentation</p>
</div>

<div class="box book">
  <p>Never lose an email again</p>
  <p class="small">Second paragrah the wants to have indentation Second paragrah the wants to have indentation Second paragrah the wants to have indentation</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution

I made the `position` of the image to `absolute`, and added `padding-left` to the container equal to more than the width of the image.
This will ensure that text added will have proper indentation.

This also results in more cleaner html structure and prevents nesting of `div`s

```css
.custom-class {
  position: relative;
  padding:5px;
  padding-left:50px;
}
.custom-class p{
  text-align:left;
  margin:0;
}


.custom-class img {
position: absolute;
top: 4px;
left: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="center custom-class" style="margin: auto;">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/28x28" style="" />
  <p style="">Never lose an email again</p>
  <p style="font-size: 0.8em">Second paragrah the wants to have indentation</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://materializecss.com/helpers.html

You should be able to wrap your img and paragraph in a div with a class of `valign-wrapper`.

```
<div class="center-align”>
    <div class="valign-wrapper">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/28x28" />
        <p style="">Never lose an email again</p>
    </div>
    <p style="font-size: 0.8em; margin-left: 28px;">Second paragrah the wants to have indentation</p>
</div>
```